# Easy way to see that $(x^2 + 5x + 4)(x^2 + 5x + 6) - 48 = (x^2 + 5x + 12)(x^2 + 5x - 2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, quadratics, factoring

As the title suggests, is there an easy way to see that$$(x^2 + 5x + 4)(x^2 + 5x + 6) - 48 = (x^2 + 5x + 12)(x^2 + 5x - 2)$$that doesn't require expanding in full? Is there a trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $a=x^2+5x+4$ we get to factor $a(a+2)-48=a^2+2a-48=(a+8)(a-6)$.

Answer (score 15):

$$(x^2 + 5x + 5-1)(x^2 + 5x + 5+1) - 48 = (x^2 + 5x + 5)^2-7^2$$

Comment: Great catch! Upvoted.

Comment: This is what was intended. Wonder what makes the admin not accept it till now @EmperorConcerto?

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2 + 5x+12 = 0$ then
$$(x^2 + 5x + 4)(x^2 + 5x + 6) - 48 = (-8)(-6)-48 = 0.$$

If $x^2 + 5x-2 = 0$ then
$$(x^2 + 5x + 4)(x^2 + 5x + 6) - 48 = 6\cdot 8-48 = 0.$$

Therefore LHS and RHS have the same zeroes. Since RHS has no double roots and both sides are polynomials of degree $4$, we conclude LHS = RHS.

Comment: You also need to see that they both have leading coefficient one

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sure, that is evident.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's just Vieta's formulas (or comparing coefficients as if $x^2+5x$ were a single variable):

$(x^2 + 5x + \color{red}4)(x^2 + 5x + \color{red}6) \color{red}{-48} = (x^2 + 5x + \color{red}{12})(x^2 + 5x \color{red}{-2})$?

$4+6=12+(-2)$, and $4\cdot 6 - 48 = 12 \cdot (-2)$, so yes.